# Can I use boost as c++20 module now?

Tags: boost, c++20, visual-c++-2019

I'm using "Visual Studio 2019 16.8 Preview 3"

```
module;

//#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>   // (1) global module fragment
export module M;

import boost;  // (2) as C++20 module
```

Can I import boost (or part of it) as C++20 module now ? I am using boost 1.73.0 installed by vcpkg.

BTW, I am not sure why this page uses `boost` as example,  https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/10/modules-1.html

Answer (score 1):

boost is not support module now since gcc12 still not fully support [c++ modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).
MSVC is the only one fully supported and on Visual Stuidio 2022 import boost works well.

MyModule.cppm

```
export module MyModule;

export import <boost/any.hpp>;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

import MyModule;

void main() {
    boost::any object;
    object = 1;
    std::cout << object.type().name();
}
```